# How to output an error using lex and yacc, to a input file containing C program which contains keywords other then the mentioned ones?

Tags: compiler-errors, compiler-construction, flex-lexer, yacc, lex

I want to construct a compiler for a subset of the **C** language with following features:

Data types: int, float, char, double
Reserved keywords: void, include, main
Control statements: while and switch
Input-output functions: printf, scanf
Operators: +, -, *, /, <=, >=, ==, >, <, !=
Compound statements and Arrays
Symbols: (, ), %, &, ;

Anything other than these I want it to be directed to `yyerror()`. 
For example if the **C** program contains boolean as a data type, it should be an error.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question (which, by the way, should be included in the body of your post, not just the title). What does your current code look like and would it not already produce an error when something unexpected shows up?

Comment: sorry if the question was not clear and i didn't have any current code, was asking how can i do it. never mind i found a way to do it by referring here : http://www.quut.com/c/ANSI-C-grammar-y.html#identifier_list